# ng-options filter based on text input value

Tags: angularjs, select, filter

I have a select drop down in Angular based HTML like below. The requirement is to filter the drop down values based on the text the user enter in a text input box. The drop down value in this select is op
How do I add the filter.

```
<select class="form-control" size="12" data-ng-model="selItem.SelectedItems"
ng-options="option as displaycodeandlabel(option,selItem.isCodeonLabel)disable when option.disabled==true for option in ::a.sData"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your `data` structure, but generally you can just use the native [**filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Here's a *working* **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.a = {};
    $scope.a.sData = [  
       {  
          "vm":"0000",
          "dm":"U.S. city average",
          "disabled":false
       },
       {  
          "vm":"0100",
          "dm":"Northeast urban",
          "disabled":false
       },
       {  
          "vm":"0200",
          "dm":"Midwest urban",
          "disabled":false
       }
    ];

    $scope.displayCodeandLabel = function(item, displayCode) {
      return displayCode ? item.vm + " " + item.dm : item.dm;      
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    <hr>
    <select class="form-control" size="12" data-ng-model="selItem.SelectedItems" ng-options="option as displayCodeandLabel(option, selItem.isCodeonLabel) 
disable when option.disabled == true for option in a.sData | filter: search"></select>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edit your question posting your data structure please.

Comment: "options": [{
    "vm": "0000",
    "dm": "U.S. city average",
    "disabled": false
   }, {
    "vm": "0100",
    "dm": "Northeast urban",
    "disabled": false
   }, {
    "vm": "0200",
    "dm": "Midwest urban",
    "disabled": false
   }
   ]

Comment: Please, edit your question posting the **complete** structure and also the `displaycodeandlabel()` function, so I could provide a good help.

Comment: $scope.checktodisplayCodenLabel = function(item,displayCode){
   if(displayCode == true){
    return item.vm+" "+item.dm;
   }
   else{
    return item.dm;
   }
 };

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

<select class="form-control" size="12" data-ng-model="selItem.SelectedItems" 
ng-options="option as displaycodeandlabel(option, selItem.isCodeonLabel) 
disable when option.disabled == true for option in  | filter: search"></select>

Comment: Your `function` is named `checktodisplayCodenLabel()` but in your view you have `displaycodeandlabel()`...

Comment: sorry,yup it is displaycodeandlabel correct. I just changed the name while copying the SELECT tag

Comment: ok . cool. thanks.  assuming there is one more filter(say to remove empty spaces in &nbsp;Midwest Urban) can we do something like this,                     <select class="form-control" size="12" data-ng-model="selItem.SelectedItems" ng-options="option as displayCodeandLabel(option, selItem.isCodeonLabel) 
disable when option.disabled == true for option in a.sData | replaceNBSP | filter: search"></select> where replaceNBSP just removes &nbsp;

Comment: I don't know if I got what you want.. do you want to display items without space? Like "MidweastUrban" for example?

Comment: It works. But when I add another filter | replaceNBSP, the select drop down values are undefined

Comment: No. basically we get the json something like                                                        u.s                                                                                                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;midwest                                                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;south   here midwest and south are under U.S. so need to remove &nbsp; with SPACE that is what replaceNBSP will do. so need to add one more filter

Comment: Do you have a filter called `replaceNBSP`?

Comment: I got it worked. I added filter:replaceNBSP | filter:search. thank you for your wonderful time

Comment: Can you check it as correct answer? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)